# How to get latest value from BehaviorSubject?

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

How can I retrieve the latest value from `BehaviorSubject` on [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)?

Some background info: I'm using RxJava to implement MVVM pattern. My ViewModel encapsulates "bindable properties" that are `BehaviorSubject`s. I'm binding them to UI elements as observables, ensuring that the interface gets constantly updated (and thanks to using `BehaviorSubject`, it's going to happen even if the subscription takes place after setting the value).

I would still like to be able to access the latest (the actual) "raw" value of the property, for business logic.

How do I do that?

Surely `BehaviorSubject` caches it somehow, given that it republishes the latest value for whoever subscribes to it.

And yet `BehaviorSubject.last()` only returns an `Observable<T>`, and it doesn't seem to expose any methods of `T` return type.

I know I could cache it myself, but it feels redundant.

I guess I could also create a throw-away subscription in my getter, only to obtain the latest value with it and then return it to the calling code, but this seems clunky.

Is there anything neater on hand?

Comment: Look at hasValue and getValue methods on the subject itself.

Comment: Well, that's about the first thing I was looking for ;) Unfortunately, it doesn't expose such methods, hence the question.

Comment: RxJava has these methods since 1.0.6:http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html#method_summary

Comment: @akarnokd RxAndroid seems to be based on RxJava 1.0.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the reason behind it is that RxAndroid by default depends on RxJava 1.0.4, where Subjects didn't expose `getValue` nor `hasValue` yet.

Thanks to @akarnokd for helping me realize that.

As it turns out, all it takes to resolve the problem is to manually add a dependency on latest version of RxJava side-by-side with RxAndroid dependency in `build.gradle`. As of now that would be:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.11'
```

See https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/171

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you use `blockingGet()`

```
subject.onNext(subject.blockingLast(null))
```